# $.get() not working onclick of a link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to update a table in my database when a user clicks on a link. I want to do it without loading another page

```
<a href="#" onclick="capturehit()">Like</a>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
function capturehit() {
$.get("/sub/updatehit/?aid=<?php echo $article_id; ?>&uid=<?php echo $userid; ?>");
return false;
}
</script>
```

sub is my controller. I am using Codeigniter.

The problem is that this is not working. When I comment $.get() and add an alert("Hello") there appears an alert box on click. But I don't know why $.get() doesn't work.

I've had problems with ajax and jquery before also while using forms and in those cases I had to resort to loading of the entire page. In this case I can't do that, I don't wanna do that. Please help me in figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Try to see in developer tools what you get back from the server (normally called the Net tab).

Comment: i checked in Network, xhr - its showing nothing. I mean nothing is happening

Comment: Try to just add some simple echo statement in updatehit.php and see if you get that string back.

Comment: And of course you have already checked that navigating in browser to the URL `/sub/updatehit.php/?aid=123&uid=1` works how you expect?

Comment: The php handler might not return anything if there are a bunch of if statements it's looking for based on $_GET data it expects to receive.

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery first in the page?

Comment: @StacyJ Does it show any errors in your Console?

Comment: did you check if your server actually gets hit when the .get() fires? Is there a hit in the access log for it? If there is, then the JS is working fine and the problem is with your server-side stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have using jquery , so why you dont try with jquery click function ?

```
 $(function(){
    $("#element").click(function(){
       $.get("/sub/updatehit/?aid=<?php echo $article_id; ?>&uid=<?php echo $userid; ?>");
       return false;
    }) 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return false you will get an alert box. Try removing the return condition from the script.

Comment: but wouldn't that load a new page if I have to call a php page

Comment: No, not if you're doing it through `JQuery $.get`.  Just make sure your submit button is triggering the function and not submitting the page.

Comment: there is no submit button. Its a link

Comment: Same difference.  Is your PHP handler returning anything when you test it by going to the PHP page manually?

Comment: when I manually go to the php page, its echoing "Hello" which I put there to test

Comment: That's good but you need to goto the page with all that stuff after the ? attached just like your `$.get` is doing. Let me know the result. P

Answer (score 0):

isn't a typo there?

```
/sub/updatehit.php/? //shoudn't that be updatehit.php?aid=...
```

Comment: I made the change in the question. Its not working with the change as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this order of jQuery lib and script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function capturehit() {
    $.get("/sub/updatehit/?aid=<?php echo $article_id; ?>&uid=<?php echo $userid; ?>");
  }
</script>
```

It seems that you are `missing the jQuery library at top of this script`. Thats why `alert()` happens but your function call is not getting fired because there `might not be jQuery available before this script` in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you use **CodeIgniter** and that "sub" is a controller.
So, "updatehit" must be a method of your controller.
You want to receive these two parameters: **aid** and **uid**

You "sub" controller should look like this:

```
<?php
class Sub extends CI_Controller {

    public function updatehit($aid, $uid)
    {

    }
}
```

Or this:

```
<?php
class Sub extends CI_Controller {

    public function updatehit()
    {
        $aid = $this->input->get('aid');
        $uid = $this->input->get('uid');
    }
}
```

It's how CodeIgniter works.
Remember that **CodeIgniter uses a segment-based approach**. To call your updatehit() method (and pass two parameters, for example aid = 2 and uid = 3), the URL must looks like:

http://www.example.com/sub/updatehit/2/3/

So your javascript code becomes:

```
function capturehit() {
    $.get("/sub/updatehit/<?php echo $article_id; ?>/<?php echo $userid; ?>");
    return false;
}
```

In a more proper way, use jQuery click event (see EnterJQ response):

Like

```
$(function(){
    $("a#like").click(function(){
        $.get("/sub/updatehit/<?php echo $article_id; ?>/<?php echo $userid; ?>/");
        return false;
    });
})
```

See [CodeIgniter URLs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) for more infos.